# How can I check If Keyboard is open or not in Appium using JAVA and ADB command

Tags: java, adb, appium

I am trying to check, if android default keyboard is open or not. I did not find anything to check keyboard using JAVA and ADB command in Appium.

Comment: `adb shell "dumpsys input | grep InputMethod | grep -o 'visible=[^,]*'"`

Comment: Just in case: could you please tell why you need this verification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this ADB command to check keyboard is opened or not.

```
adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mInputShown
```

In output `mInputShown=true` if keyboard is open and `mInputShown=false` if keyboard is closed.
JAVA code:

```
String cmd[] = new String[]{"adb", "shell", "dumpsys", "input_method", "|" ,"grep", "mInputShown"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);    
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(        
process.getInputStream()));
String output = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: `grep` and `output.contains()` in your java code are redundant - why are looking for a string and then a substring when you could be looking just for the substring right away?