# How to verify Keyboard is opened or not in the screen using java

Tags: java, selenium

How to verify Keyboard is opened or not in the screen.That means if Keyboard opened i have to hide or else have to open keyboard.
Using Appium Version : 4.1.0

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0</version>
```

Comment: Anyone please suggest??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check If Keyboard is open or not in Appium using JAVA and ADB command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582183/how-can-i-check-if-keyboard-is-open-or-not-in-appium-using-java-and-adb-command)

Comment: No. this is not duplicate. it is much more different

Comment: If you read the link I posted, there are multiple solutions offered.  If the poster isn't asking more or less the same exact thing you are asking, then please explain what the difference is, other than "it is much more different."

Answer (score 1):

I use the default function provided, "**isKeyboardShown**()"

For iOS

```
getIosDriver().isKeyboardShown();
```

returns true if the keyboarad is open, false otherwise.

http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/keys/is-keyboard-shown/

Answer (score 0):

Try below the snippet to identify that Soft Keyboard is opened or closed. Hope it helps!

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
    Log("Soft_Keyboard displaying");
    //write your requirement here to close SKeyBoard if required
} else {
    Log("Soft_Keyboard is not displaying");
    //write your requirement here to open SKeyBoard if required
}
```